# Hibernate without spring with annotations

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, annotations

i want to use Hiberante without Spring and i have some trobules with packagesToScan... Hibernate can not find my entities. I'm working with tomcat7.

This my configurazion:

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ccc</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ccc</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">com.ccc.db.entity</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried to move classes from build folder to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`packagesToScan` is a Spring feature.

As far as I remember you cannot configure Hibernate Core (not Hibernate EntityManager) to scan classpath for annotated entities.

So, if using Hibernate Core API (`Session`/`SessionFactory`) is a requirement you have to enumerate annotated classes manually (for example, as `<mapping class = "..." />`).

Otherwise you can switch to Hibernate EntityManager (JPA API, `EntityManager`/`EntityManagerFactory`) that supports classpath scanning out of the box.

Comment: I didn't understand you last paragraph. The mapping class is my only choice without Spring? Thank you